# Update child values in Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement updating Firebase database once a user taps on a button. When the user logs in (with Facebook in my case), a data structure is created successfully with the initial values in the data tree created.

What I want to accomplish is once the user is in the app and they create a new item it saves it to the database, hence updates the values under one of the already created child values. See my code and screenshot for reference - thanks for any help!

```
// user taps button to send item to be updated in Firebase data tree
func confirmAddPlace() {

    // add place to tableview array
    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
    guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else { return }

    let credentials = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Something went wrong with our FB user: ", error ?? "")
            return
        }

    guard let uid = user?.uid else {
        return
    }
    // here is where i am having issues
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().root.child("Users").child(uid).child("Places")
    let values = ["place": self.placeNameLabel.text]
    ref.updateChildValues(values)
})

    animateOut()
}
```

[image]

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        let placeID = place.placeID
        placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let place = place else {
                return
            }
        })
        let selectedPlace = place.formattedAddress
        if let name = selectedPlace as String!
        {
            self.placeNameLabel.text = "Are you sure you would like to add \(name) to your places?"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, did you manage to solve this problem? if so how please?

Answer (score 11):

You want to change the value of `Places`, which is the value in the child of `child(uid)`.

```
let values = ["place": self.placeNameLabel.text]
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().root.child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(["Places": values])
```

Comment: Thanks! That does help with one thing I am trying to. A couple additions though...I am  trying to create an item every time the user adds a new place to the array...so not just updating the same child value, as well as only save a part of a string to the database. I have added additional code to the post for what I am passing after user selects from the GMSAutocompleteViewController....so I want to only save the name value to Firebase. Thanks again!

Comment: how can I get the updated node's value in callback of upateChildValues?

Answer (score 0):

user3708224 - You could try this:

```
let values = ["place": self.placeNameLabel.text]
// create a child reference that uses a date as the key
let date = Date()
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().root.child("users").child(uid).child(date).updateChildValues(["Places": values])
```

If you want more control of what components are in the date object try this:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)

// you can do the same with [.month, .day, .hour, .minute, and more]
// This will allow you to have control of how frequently they can update the DB
// And it will allow you to sort by date
```

If you want to upload it to Firebase as a String try this:

```
/**
 This function returns the Date as a String
 - "Year-Month-Day"
 If the character ' / ' is used in place of ' - ' Firebase will make each component child of the previous component. 
 */
func getDate() -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        // hours + min:  -\(calendar.component(.hour, from: date))-\(calendar.component(.minute, from: date))
        return "\(calendar.component(.year, from: date))-\(calendar.component(.month, from: date))-\(calendar.component(.day, from: date))"

    }

let values = ["place": self.placeNameLabel.text]
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().root.child("users").child(uid).child(getDate()).updateChildValues(["Places": values])
```